# Key Render through Node Editor adding a border / shrinking video

Tags: rendering

Both imput videos are 1080x1920, yet the render comes out as footage 1/2 the size of the resolution, after keying with the node editor.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your render settings?

Comment: Is the render resolution for the project set at 100%?

Comment: Yes, the resolution is set to 100%. Here are my settings https://imgur.com/a/07qVzfb